# report error when GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT is not input in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this very simple Ruby code:

```
#!/res/software/pkg/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby -w
require( 'getoptlong' )
opts = GetoptLong.new( [ '--netlist_file', GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT ] )
puts 'error in getting netlist' << opts.error_message.to_s()
```

The output is:

```
cs059:Florida_domains$ ~/test.rb
error in getting netlist
```

How can I error out when any argument that is GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT is NOT input?
Is there a generic way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require( 'getoptlong' )
begin
  opts = GetoptLong.new( [ '--netlist_file', GetoptLong::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT ] )

  opts.each do |option, arg|
    case option
      when "--netlist_file"
        #assign the argument to my_var or do whatever you need to do with it
        my_var = arg
    end
rescue => e
  puts "Error in arguments"
  puts e.to_s
end
```